# mov command with vs. without parenthesis?

Tags: variables, assembly, x86, nasm

I don't understand what is the difference between these two statements

```
mov [var] , 10
```

and

```
mov var,10
```

in assembly?

Comment: For which assembler (NASM, MASM, TASM, ...)? It matters, since they use different syntax.

Comment: While Michael's answer is complete and correct I just want to make sure you realize the brackets mean **dereference**.

Comment: umm is derefence mean a pointer sign?

Answer (score 6):

For a variable like this:

```
var: db 0
```

The instruction `mov var,10` would not be allowed by NASM, because in NASM syntax writing `var` like that (without square brackets) means that you want the address of `var` as an immediate. And there's no variant of `mov` that takes an `immediate, immediate` operand pair.

Adding the square brackets makes it a reference to an address in memory. So `mov [var], 10` means store the value 10 at `var`. Actually you'd have to specify the size of the value to store as well, e.g. `mov byte [var], 10`. Otherwise NASM doesn't know if you want to store a byte, a word, or a dword, because the immediate 10 could be represented in any of those sizes.

Note that in MASM/TASM syntax `mov var, 10` and `mov [var], 10` would mean the same thing in this case (they would both have the same meaning as `mov [var], 10` in NASM sytax).